# How to use colour scheme and select colours for web

Tags: website-design, color, color-theory

Some of the clients have very bad logo colours, which are nightmares to develop or design websites for these kind of clients. Also, some of them have a good shapes design, but still the colours are miserably chosen. so how can I deal with kinds of problems.

I would like to have a better understand of colours theory. can anybody lead or recommend me with some resources and materials? Please

Thanks a lot for all of you.

Comment: Are clients open to you altering their branding? Whether or not you personally  like the colors, doesn't mean you can freely change them much of the time. Branding often needs to remain consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer probably will not answer your question, because you have not a specific question, but it is meant to be a guideline for you to investigate further.

> I would like to have a better understand of colours theory

I am not sure if you have the concepts right.

We have:

- Color science (Light, physiology...)
- Color theory
- Color psychology
- Corporative design guidelines
- Color trends
- and there is good taste

> very bad logo colours

This is the first thing you need to analyze. Why they are bad? What could be a better option? Can you modify a bit the tone, or the hue or saturation, to make them better? Are there already some corporative guidelines?

Is the "bad logo color" an intrinsic relationship problem? Is it just a matter of taste? Does it has a contrast problem?

I can go on and on... You need to have a methodology to analyze problems and then you will have solutions at your fingertips.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guides. I will read more about the listed topics.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same experience myself. One of my professors in a web design class showed me [Adobe Kuler](https://color.adobe.com/). You can create your own color themes and use other peoples themes. It even gives you the hexadecimal number of each color.

Comment: OP wants to learn more color theory, how can Kuler help if it just creates color schemes?

Comment: Read the title one more tine

Comment: read the whole question; the title is not everything. Don't be so trigger-happy when answering a question.

Comment: I did. His clients have bad colors and I gave him a resource to help. The more I use Adobe Kuler, the more understanding I have on which colors go together better with each other.